# Cannot click "Ok Google" detection and "Screen search" on Nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, google-now, 7.0-nougat

[image: Google App]
[image: Screen Search]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

This are the screen shots from my Nexus 5. Recently I flashed Android N and installed Gapps but I am not able to turn them on.

Comment: Is your default language in your phone settings (not Google search settings) set to English (US)? If it is at English (UK), or any other language it might not work.